# Can I use Elasticsearch free of charge?

Tags: elasticsearch

I just wanna know if Elasticsearch is free. I know it is open source but I checked the website and I didn't find anything about pricing, though I did found subscription with no pricing. So, is it free for long-term use?

Just to let you know, I'm working with the MERN stack (MongoDB, Express.js, React.js, Node.js) and socket IO.

If Elasticsearch is free, then is it going to work and integrate with my stack smoothly?

Comment: Guess you need to subscribe for support. https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you want managed hosting from elastic.co, they charge you according to several variables. You can find the pricing here: https://www.elastic.co/cloud/elasticsearch-service/pricing

If you want to use the open-source version, stand up your own servers and manage your own deployment, the code is at no cost and can be found here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch

It's super-important to remember that spinning up VMs on the cloud is **NOT** free. In fact, you might spend more money on cloud VMs than using elastic.co's managed services. Elasticsearch is a memory hog and I found that very quickly, and with minor load, I had to dedicate 4GBs of RAM just for the Java heap space. Under heavy load, you'd have to dedicate more. All of that costs money.

As far as integrating with your mainly-javascript stack, it shouldn't be a problem. This library is very useful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch

Comment: Be aware that if you need features like access control, you have to pay their licence.

Comment: Excactly. All security features (including things as basic as "encrypted communications") require a paid licence: https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions

Comment: Just to leave here another comment. Yes they are tricky bastards and they charge you even for basic stuff like securing your connection with ssl (which is included in msot open source tools now days). They are tricky bastards because you will not find this detail unless you read the docs carefully (and some discuss posts)

Comment: Perhaps this needs to be updated, their Basic and Free-Forever build includes RBAC and TLS.

Comment: @GeoC. based on this blog post, they've made security free of charge, starting in versions 6.8.0 and 7.1.0 
https://www.elastic.co/blog/security-for-elasticsearch-is-now-free

Answer (score -2):

Elasticsearch is free of cost and open source. They charge for services like support, consultancy etc. and for plugins like kibana.

Comment: Kibana is Open source
https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/LICENSE.md

Comment: This is not true!  If you need to secure elasticsearch in ANY way (ssl, user/roles, authentication) you have to pay.

Comment: Although your comment is correct, it might mislead new users. It IS possible to terminate SSL and set up (simple) authentication for the open source verison of Elasticsearch and/or Kibana completely for free; you just have to reverse proxy it with something like Nginx or Apache. It is however correct that if you'd like a nice user UI and SSL termination directly on the standalone ES instance, you have to pay.

Comment: You can use the free plugin readonlyrest to enable HTTP Authentication, SSL and ACL.